# How to stop PGAdmin 4 auto detecting a ghost instance?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I had Postgresql 9.6 installed (on Windows 10) and did a complete uninstall including the data directory and all old copies of PgAdmin and there are no environment variables relating to this or any other old Postgres installation either.

I recently installed Postgresql 11 and PgAdmin 4 v3.6 using EnterpriseDB installer. When I run PgAdmin 4 it aurto detects a postgresql instance called 9.6 - though the details tell me it is actually my v11 instance with the same port number and password etc.  The only difference is that it is pointing to the non-existent old data directory.

I have searched for a stray postgresql.conf file (and can't find one as it was in the deleted data directory!).  As there is also no environment variables, no binaries and no data I can't understand how PgAdmin is auto detecting this ghost.  Any suggestions on how to correct it?

**EDIT:**

- I have tried deleting all cookies relating to PgAdmin and Postgresql in Chrome too - this had no effect
- I have also double checked that there is no postgresql 9.6 service running (but that just confirms the above where PgAdmin tells me it is called 9.6 but actually is a v11 instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting pgAdmin4 config file `pgadmin4.db` located at %APPDATA%\pgAdmin\

Restart pgAdmin4 and check.

Comment: Worked like a charm! So simple.